# Why should I use ribbon/hystrix/eureka instead of docker+haproxy for a microservice?

Tags: docker, microservices

I am trying to find reasons of using  Ribbon+Hysterix+Eureka for load balancing/fault tolernace and service discovery?

Why can't I simply deploy my micro service using docker-compose and with help of https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-haproxy, don't I get all the advantages?

In fact with docker-compose, dockercloud-haproxy - I don't need even service discovery, right? If I have Zuul Proxy server, can't I register a fixed URL for my service that points to this docker container run by happroxy?

Thanks.